# Nyquist plot for quasi polynomials

Tags: matlab, controls, timedelay, nyquist

I want to analyze the quasi polynomial given as p(x)=x+exp(-x) using its Nyquist plot. I want the Nyquist plot of p(iw)/(iw+1). How to do this in Matlab? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasons people spend thousands of dollars on Matlab is their extensive documentation and help functionality. You should use that.

Typing in

```
doc nyquist
```

will take you to the help explorer with [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/nyquist.html).

What you probably want to supply it with a model; you can do that by evaluating your exp-function for a range of points, and then using `frd` to convert these discrete measurement points to a system `nyquist` can work with. No magic, and everything linked from the `nyquist` help page :)

Comment: That is known to me sir. But that is only for linear systems and I know how to use it. But I want this for quasi polynomials given in the question. Also /i don't want to approximate the exponential term.

Comment: @user3563283: It's not only for linear systems. it's for *systems*, and I anticipated that you think that, which is why I referred to `frd`.

Comment: I never used `frd`. I am not getting how to use it from `Matlab` help.

Comment: I really don't know how to explain it better than Matlab does. In fact, matlabs `frd` help page even has an **example** doing something very similar to what you need.